# Where to get older version od kendo ui open source?

Tags: kendo-ui

Im interested in getting an older version of Kendo UI open source, specifically the Kendo.Web - 2012.3.1114 release. I need it beacause im using jquery 1.8.3 in my project and i cant change that. So the question is: Where can i get these specific realese?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you try http://www.kendoui.com/web/whats-new.aspx?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about where to find some software version and not about using it or programming.

Answer (score 3):

They are all available on kendo's cdn.

http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2012.3.1114/js/kendo.web.min.js

http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.default.min.css
http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2013.3.1119/styles/kendo.common.min.css